# Must Salatul Tasbih be performed at least once in a lifetime?

Tags: salat

Our Beloved Prophet Muhammed (*Sallallaho Alihiwassallam*) is reported to have prayed *Salatul Tasbih* and then said to that this *salah* should be prayed once a day, if you can not pray once a day then every Friday, and even if this is not possible then once a month and even if this is not possible then once a year and even if this is not possible then at least once in a lifetime.

Is it necessary that this prayer must be performed at least once in a lifetime?  Is it a sin if someone doesn't pray this prayer at all during his life?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is dispute among Sunni scholars over the validity of *Salatul Tasbih*. The root of this dispute comes from differing views over the authenticity of this hadith:

> The Messenger of Allah () said to al-Abbas ibn AbdulMuttalib: Abbas,
>   my uncle, shall I not give you, shall I not present to you, shall I
>   not donate to you, shall I not produce for you ten things? If you act
>   upon them, Allah will forgive you your sins, first and last, old and
>   new, involuntary and voluntary, small and great, secret and open.
>   These are the ten things: you should pray four rak'ahs, reciting in
>   each one Fatihat al-Kitab and a surah. When you finish the recitation
>   of the first rak'ah you should say fifteen times while standing:
>   "Glory be to Allah", "Praise be to Allah", "There is no god but
>   Allah", "Allah is most great". Then you should bow and say it ten
>   times while bowing. Then you should raise your head after bowing and
>   say it ten times. Then you should kneel down in prostration and say it
>   ten times while prostrating yourself. Then you should raise your head
>   after prostration and say it ten times. Then you should prostrate
>   yourself and say it ten times. Then you should raise your head after
>   prostrating and say it ten times in every rak'ah. You should do that
>   in four rak'ahs. If you can observe it once daily, do so; if not, then
>   once weekly; if not, then once a month; if not, then once a year; if
>   not, then once in your lifetime.
>
> [Sunan Abi Dawud](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/5#48)

Some scholars such as Abu Dawud and Al-Albani have classified it as *sahih* (authentic), while others such as Ahmad ibn Hanbal and Ibn Taimiyah have classified it as *da'eef* (weak). Still, even the scholars that have considered *Salatul Tasbih* as valid have classified it as *mustahab*, so there is no sin attached if one does not perform it.

Source (Arabic):
http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=2501