# Is it valid to offer salat ul tasbeeh after jummah prayer?

Tags: salat, jumuah, nafl

After performing jummah pray I uses to offer salat ul tasbeeh pray, but my grandma said to perform salat ul tasbeeh before jummah. So I just want to ask is it valid to offer salat ul tasbeeh after jummah prayer?

Answer (score 2):

This prayer is considered a nafl and has no specific timing -as in the hadith quoting it there was no mentioning of a special time-. So basically you could perform it at any time of the day or night unless it is a time one shouldn't pray (non obligatory prayers) at.
**Note** that the word jumua'h in the hadith (which soundness is highly questionable) refers to week (not the day of jumu'ah/friday necessarily, as Arabs used to refer to the week as "jumu'ah"), so the hadith says if it's possible to pray it once a day do so, if you are able to perform it once a week do so, if you are able to perform it once a month do so, if you are able to perform it once a year do so and if not perform it at least once in lifetime. This hadith explains how this prayer should be done.

Also note that the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/5/48) about this prayer is considered as da'if by most scholars or even fabricated by the hanbali school of fiqh and therefore they reject it:
See for example [islamqa #14320](https://islamqa.info/en/14320)  and [#145112](https://islamqa.info/en/145112), but among the salafi scholars al-Albani has considered it as hassan.

Also relevant [Must Salatul Tasbih be performed at least once in a lifetime?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4288/must-salatul-tasbih-be-performed-at-least-once-in-a-lifetime)