# Can Salat-ul-Tasbeeh be prayed during Dahwa e kubra?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings, nafl

Can we pray Salat-ul-Tasbeeh during dahwa e kubra (time before start of zuhur prayer) ?

Answer (score 2):

As the hadith on which this prayer is based is very doubtful (See  for example: [Must Salatul Tasbih be performed at least once in a lifetime?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4288/must-salatul-tasbih-be-performed-at-least-once-in-a-lifetime) and [Is it valid to offer salat ul tasbeeh after jummah prayer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43552/is-it-valid-to-offer-salat-ul-tasbeeh-after-jummah-prayer)) and as I really have no idea what dahwa e kubra means, but I know that some madhhabs consider a period of time before dhohr prayer as among the times of karaha (times where praying optional prayers in general is frowned upon) depending to the madhhab you follow praying a nafl prayer during this time would be strongly discouraged or permissible, assuming this prayer is nafl and authentic.